# Import and use NPM package (Sluggo) in Astro

Tags: npm-package, astrojs

I want to use this NPM package, Sluggo (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sluggo), in Astro, in the frontmatter of an Astro component.

After installation, I import it following Astro docs:

```
import { sluggo } from 'sluggo';
```

When I try to use it following Sluggo docs:

```
var sluggedString = sluggo('@ monkey\'s are elab؉؉orate fools##');
```

I get this error: ****vite_ssr_import_1**.sluggo is not a function**

I can understand that "sluggo" is not a function, but how can I access the function inside the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `sluggo` is not a named export, so you  need to do:

```js
import sluggo from 'sluggo';
```